# How can i copy an image from one folder to another?

Tags: java, swing, file, directory, copy

I am tasked by my Instructor to create a program. Creating the GUI was not a problem. Some of the events are also not difficult.But when i was using a JFileChooser to upload a photo and store its location in my database(storing location was not a problem).

Now the PROBLEM is, my program can't copy the file to my folder because it can't locate my folder. And another problem is when i move my program to another location the same error occurs....

How would i make my program locate the folder?

My code for uploading file is:

```
     public void choosePhotoStudent(JLabel lblPhoto){        
            FileNameExtensionFilter filter = new FileNameExtensionFilter("JPG & PNG Images", "jpg" , "png");
            jFileChooser1.setFileFilter(filter);
            int returnVal = jFileChooser1.showOpenDialog(null);
            if(returnVal == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION){
                fileOrigin = new File(jFileChooser1.getSelectedFile().getAbsolutePath().toString());
                fileDestination = new File(getClass().getResource("\\SHIELD\\src\\shield\\resources\\students\\"+jFileChooser1.getSelectedFile().getName())+"");
                fileDestinationTemp = new File("\\resources\\\\students\\\\"+jFileChooser1.getSelectedFile().getName());
                //fileDestination = new File("\\\\resources\\\\students\\\\"+jFileChooser1.getSelectedFile().getName());
                //Methods.copyFile(fileOrigin, fileDestination, lblPhoto);
//code below is for me to see what is wrong
                System.out.println(fileOrigin+"");/prints origin of image
                System.out.println(fileDestination+"");//copy location (prints null)
                System.out.println(fileDestinationTemp+"");//location in database - this one is fine
               }
        }
```

The method i used to copy the file is fine, the only problem is the variable fileDestination is null.

Comment: `(getClass().getResource(.."` Will fail unless the directory is on the run-time class-path of the app.  Is it?

Comment: Instead of storing the name, or relative path, store the absolute path of the file to your database, in case the program is always going to run on a disk that will have this path. Other option is to use a relative path for storing and an environment specific path which when added would give you the absolute path on your system

Comment: It seems you are working of an SMB share judging from the '\\' (could be wrong)? Perhaps your better of using JCIFS ( http://jcifs.samba.org/ ) or Apache VFS ( https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-vfs/ ).

Comment: Thank you!!! I know it's okay for the program to run on a specific directory but when i passed it to my instructor and he copied to another folder...the program can't locate the folder I specified...so he said i should work on it.... Now I want the program to get the destination folder where ever i put the program....